# I can't align my header very well

Tags: html, css

I aligned my header with left: 100px; etc with px's. Then I changed it to %'s, as in left: 10%;. It looked good on the other computer, but now looks bad on my computer. Also when the window gets smaller it goes all together. I want it to look good on all the computers. The link is: http://www.avatarcentral.x10.mx/. The coding is as followed:

```
    <!header part>
    <div style="position: fixed; top: 15px; right: 0px; font-size: 23.777px; line-height: 35px; left: 11.777%; color: white;"><a href="http://www.avatarcentral.x10.mx/home" id="nounderlineurl"><font color='white'>HOME</font></a></div>
    <div style="position: fixed; top: 15px; right: 0px; font-size: 23.777px; line-height: 35px; left: 23.5%; color: white;"><?php if ($user['purchased'] == '1'){ ?><a href="http://www.avatarcentral.x10.mx/account" id="nounderlineurl"><font color='white'>ACCOUNT</font></a><?php }else{ ?><a href="http://www.avatarcentral.x10.mx/purchase" id="nounderlineurl"><font color='white'>PURCHASE</font></a><?php } ?></div>
    <div style="position: fixed; top: 15px; right: 0px; font-size: 23.777px; line-height: 35px; left: 68.777777777%; color: white;"><a href="http://www.avatarcentral.x10.mx/contact" id="nounderlineurl"><font color='white'>CONTACT</font></a></div>
    <?php if ($logged == false){ ?>
    <div style="position: fixed; top: 15px; right: 0px; font-size: 23.777px; line-height: 35px; left: 81%; color: white;"><a href="http://www.avatarcentral.x10.mx/signin" id="nounderlineurl"><font color='white'>SIGN IN</font></a></div>
    <?php
    }else{
    ?>
    <div style="position: fixed; top: 15px; right: 0px; font-size: 23.777px; line-height: 35px; left: 81%; color: white;"><a href="http://www.avatarcentral.x10.mx/signout" id="nounderlineurl"><font color='white'>SIGN OUT</font></a></div>
    <?php
     }
    ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have a website that's trying to sell custom made websites, but you can't fix your own HTML issue?

Comment: @j08691 I code php and stuff for the website, I can't code html that well though.

Comment: your code is messed with unnecessary code. Try to rewrite it. Add padding-left to avoid clubbing

Comment: @BaTmaN I know lol I am not a very good coder anyway. I'm just coding this website because its summer and I'm really bored.

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ffypkoyv/ ?

Comment: @Dmitriy, thank you but that isn't what I'm looking for. I'm looking for no background color (I can change that easily though), and them all to be on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `right:0px` `left:11%` such tags. Then make .css file and add `float:left` `margin:0 auto;` etc

Comment: This doesn't make it how I want it to be, I want the line-height to be 35px; (I kept that and stuff) but that makes it all the way to the side do I just add paddnig-left then? idk I want it to be Home, Purchases, Custom Made Websites, Contact, Sign In